# Probability of Lottery Scenarios

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A lottery ticket system has you circle three numbers out of the numbers 1-20. When the lottery is drawn three numbers are chosen at random (without replacement) out of the numbers 1-20. What is the probability you win the lottery in the following situations:
>
> a. 1 number match?
>
> b. 2 numbers match?
>
> c. 3 numbers match?
>
> d. 0 numbers match?
>
> e.Show the first four parts are correct by showing the sum equals 1

For all these scenarios the denominator is $\binom{20}{3}$ since their are 20 numbers and 3 numbers trying to match which gives us 540 being the denominator for all these values.  Now I did all these calculations but did not get 1 when I added them up and I want to see what I am doing wrong.

For part a) I said $\binom{3}{1}\binom{20}{2}$ is our numerator since one out of the three numbers, one number must be choosen and for each of these ways their is 20 choose 2 ways to select the numbers that don't match ours.  However, when I did this I got 570/540 which means I definitely did something wrong.

For part b) I did a similar format but instead $\binom{3}{2}\binom{20}{1}$ and got 60/540 which makes sense.

For part c) I put our denominator over 1 and got 1/540.

Finally for d), I got $\binom{3}{0}\binom{20}{3}$, and got 3 which again doesn't make sense.

Clearly I am doing something wrong but I feel like my logic is correct.  What doesn't look right here?

Comment: In all cases, the second choice is being made from the $17$ number that don't match, not from all $20$ numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $3$ are chosen, then $20-3=17$ are not.

a) $$\dfrac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{17}{2}}{\dbinom{20}{3}}$$

b) $$\dfrac{\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{17}{1}}{\dbinom{20}{3}}$$

c) $$\dfrac{\dbinom{3}{3}\dbinom{17}{0}}{\dbinom{20}{3}}$$

d) $$\dfrac{\dbinom{3}{0}\dbinom{17}{3}}{\dbinom{20}{3}}$$

e) $$\dfrac{\dbinom{3}{0}\dbinom{17}{3}+\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{17}{2}+\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{17}{1}+\dbinom{3}{3}\dbinom{17}{0}}{\dbinom{20}{3}} = \dfrac{680+408+51+1}{1140} = 1$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I messed up the denominator so all that stuff makes sense!  Awesome!